# layout_weight with different layout types

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been successfully using `android:layout_weight` and the related layout arguments with `LinearLayout`. Is it possible to use the mechanism with other layout types? For example, to control column widths in `TableLayout` or `GridLayout`. How about `RelativeLayout`? Is there any other way to make a column in `TableLayout` strictly occupy, let's say, 30% of its parent?

Comment: Make those layouts as children to your Linear Layout. Weights only work with LinearLayout.

Comment: You can use weights with the LinearLayout and **all its subclasses**. `Known Direct Subclasses:
ActionMenuView, ListRowHoverCardView, ListRowView, NumberPicker, RadioGroup, SearchView, TabWidget, TableLayout, TableRow, ZoomControls`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

layout_weight is currently only useable in a LinearLayout. This is usually not a Problem, because you can pretty much build all UI's you want to use weight in with nested LinearLayouts.

[For Grid Layout i found this:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)

> "GridLayout does not provide support for the principle of weight, as defined in weight. In general, it is not therefore possible to configure a GridLayout to distribute excess space in non-trivial proportions between multiple rows or columns ... For complete control over excess space distribution in a row or column; use a LinearLayout subview to hold the components in the associated cell group."